# Creating Associative array (hardcoded key) from foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$arr` containing some information about users. Using `$arr` I want to create a new associative array with specific keys. That's what I got so far:

```
$groups = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $groups['first_key_name'] = $val->ID;
    $groups['second_key_name'] = $val->login;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a new array that has the following format:

```
'first_key_name' => $val->ID
'second_key_name' => $val->login
'first_key_name' => $val->ID
'second_key_name' => $val->login
```

The problem with my current approach is when I `var_dump($groups)` I only get one key with an empty value although the array should contain at least 10 entries.

The output of `var_dump($groups)`:

```
array:1 [▼
  "first_key_name" => "4"
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does a var_dump of $arr show?

Comment: _"What I'm trying to achieve is a new array that has the following format: [...]"_ - that is not possible, you can not use the same array key more than once.

Comment: The trick is to use just `[]` to denote a new array item with numerical key

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: If you could have duplicate keys, how would it know which one to return when you did `echo $groups['first_key_name']`? Have you thought about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting your variables each time round the loop in this code

```
$groups = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $groups['first_key_name'] = $val->ID;
    $groups['second_key_name'] = $val->login;
}
```

So instead do

```
$groups = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $groups[] = [
                'first_key_name'  => $val->ID
                'second_key_name' => $val->login
               ]; 
}
```

This will create something like this

```
[0]
    [
    'first_key_name' = 1,
    'second_key_name' = 99
    ]
[1]
    [
    'first_key_name' = 2,
    'second_key_name' = 199
    ]
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You approach is overwriting the key value every time. That's why you need to use 2d array.

You can try like this:

```
$groups = [];
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $groups[] = ['first_key_name' => $val->ID, 'second_key_name' => $val->login];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here, is you are overwriting `first_key_name` and `second_key_name` in each turn of the loop. But you want to get an array with the new `key=>value` pairs.

To achieve that you have to append a new item to your array called `$groups`, like this:

```php
$groups = [];
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    $groups[] = [
        'first_key_name'  => $val->ID,
        'second_key_name' => $val->login
    ];
}
```

You may also use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this:

```php
$groups = array_map(function ($val) {
    return [
        'first_key_name'  => $val->ID,
        'second_key_name' => $val->login,
    ];
}, $arr);
```